# Unrecognisable escape sequence error

Tags: c#

I just attached my database from some other computer to my computer.everything worked fine except of this data source.It is giving an error "Unrecognizable escape sequence".

I think the error is because of the back slash but I don't know how can I resolve it because my computer's server name is this only.Please help.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=APOORVA\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=mall inventory;integrated security=true");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=APOORVA\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=mallinventory;integrated security=true");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked.Can you tell how did it help?what was wrong?

Comment: `\S` is unrecognized.  You have two choices.  One is to use @ sign to tell the compiler don't treat \ a special escape character.  Another is to escape \ itself by \\

Answer (score 1):

The compiler was seeing `\S`, and trying to interpret it as an escape-sequence (because it starts with a `\`).

Either escape the backslash by doubling it:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=APOORVA\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=mallinventory;integrated security=true");
```

Or use a verbatim string:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=APOORVA\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=mallinventory;integrated security=true");
```

Comment: thak you.how the double back slash helps.will it not change the name of the server?

Comment: No, it won't. In C# strings, for example `\n` means "new line", and `\t` means tab. That means you need some way of specifying a real backslash. The way to do that is \\. If you print the content of the variable, you will only see one backslash.

Answer (score 0):

in the case of unrecognized escape sequence you need to do this :
    "...\\SQLEXPRESS;..."
or as Harvey mentioned :
    @"...\SQLEXPRESS;..."
they are both the same.